# Print Matching line and nth line from the matched line

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to print the matched line and the 4th line from the matched line (line containing the expression I am searching for).

I have been using the following code:
`sed -n 's/^[ \t]*//; /img class=\"devil_icon/,4p' input.txt`

But this only prints the matched line.

This prints only the 4th line.
`awk 'c&&!--c;/img class=\"devil_icon/{c=4}' input.txt`

I need to print both the matched line and the 4th line only.

Comment: Use  `egrep "pattern" -A4`

Comment: @val0x00ff that prints the lines in between too.. that is: it prints next 4 lines starting from the matched line

Comment: you are saying "I am trying to print the matched line and the 4th line from the matched line". This `grep -A 4 "pattern" file | sed -n '4p'` does do exactly what you want, unless I'm misunderstanding you

Comment: no it doesn't. The output of the above code was `</td>` which is not the 4th line

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In awk, you'd do it as follows

```
awk '/pattern/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+4]}; NR in nr' file > new_file`
```

or

```
awk '/pattern/{print; nr[NR+4]; next}; NR in nr' file > new_file`
```

#### Explanation

The first solution finds all lines that match `pattern`. When it finds a match it stores the record number (`NR`) in the array `nr`. It also stores the 4th record from `NR` in the same array. This is done by the `nr[NR+4]`. Every record (`NR`) is then checked to see if it's present in the `nr` array, if so the record is printed.

The second solution works essentially the same way, except when it encounters th e `pattern` it prints that line, and then stores the 4th record ahead of it in the array `nr`, then goes to the next record. Then when `awk` encounters this 4th record the `NR in nr` block will get executed and print this +4 record there after.

#### Example

Here's an example data file, `sample.txt`.

```
$ cat sample.txt 
1
2
3
4 blah
5
6
7
8
9
10 blah
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

Using the 1st solution:

```
$ awk '/blah/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+4]}; NR in nr' sample.txt 
4 blah
8
10 blah
14
```

Using the 2nd solution:

```
$ awk '/blah/{print; nr[NR+4]; next}; NR in nr' sample.txt 
4 blah
8
10 blah
14
```

Comment: Nice, +1. You're using a lot of `awk` shortcuts here, could you add a short explanation (things like print being implied in awk and that arrays are associative etc)?

Comment: a agree with @terdon please could you explain the code a little.

Comment: @slm Thanks for improving and providing the complete answer!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I learned somthing new with it too.

Comment: It's also helpful to understand that the `NR in nr` part basically implies this: `if (NR in n) print $0` - which is performed for each line and matches when the current NR equals the previously stored line number(s) .i.e. NR+4.

Answer (score 5):

You can try the `-A` option with `grep`, which specifies how many lines after the matching line should be printed. Couple this with `sed`, and you would get the required lines.

`grep -A 4 pattern input.txt | sed -e '2,4d'`

Using `sed`, we delete the from the second line until the fourth.

Comment: This assumes a single match of `pattern` in the file.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -n 's/^[ \t]*/; /img class=\"devil_icon/,+4 { 3,5d ; p }' input.txt
```

I'm simply adding a deletion of the appropriate lines, before printing `{ 3,5d ; p }`.

Comment: your expression produces an error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to `s'`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way in Perl which can deal with an arbitrary number of matching lines:

```
perl -ne '/pattern/ && do{$c=$.; print}; $.==$c+4 && print' file > new_file`
```

In Perl. the special variable `$.` is the current line number. So, each time I find a line matching `pattern`, I print it and save its line number as `$c`. I then print again when the current line number is 4 more than the one printed previously.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/img class=\"devil_icon/{c=4};/img class=\"devil_icon/' input.txt
```

You're essentially doing a find and replace.  You can add just a *find* into the same command and it'll print both of them :)

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/pattern/{c=4};/pattern/' input.txt
```