# Match multiple regular expressions from a single file using awk

Tags: shell-script, awk, regular-expression

I'm trying to parse a HTML file using shell scripting.

There are 4 different regular expressions that i need to catch: `name=` , `age=` , `class=` , `marks=`.

Using

```
grep "name=\|age=\|class=\|marks=" student.txt
```

I'm able to get the required lines, but along with these matching lines I also need to print the second line from each match which contains the score.

Referring to the question: [Print Matching line and nth line from the matched line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88038/print-matching-line-and-nth-line-from-the-matched-line).

I modified the code to:

```
awk '/name=\|age=\|class=\|marks=/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+2]}; NR in nr' student.txt
```

But this does not seem to work.  How do I search for multiple regular expressions in the same `awk` command?

Comment: You can't realistically parse tag-based markup languages like HTML and XML using bash or utilities such as grep, sed or cut. If you just want to dump/render HTML, see (lynx|elinks|links|links2|w3m) -dump, html2text, or vilistextum. For parsing out pieces of data, see tidy + (xmlstarlet|xmlgawk|xpath|xml2), or learn xslt. Ask #xml and #html for more help. See http://xrl.us/bkrxog and http://xrl.us/p0ny

This is a factoid returned from greybot on irc.freenode.org

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with:

```
awk '/foo/||/bar/' Input.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

`awk` regexps are extended regexps while `grep`'s without `-E` are basic regexp. With extended regexp:

```
awk '/name=|age=|class=|marks=/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+2]}; NR in nr'
```

Note that standard basic regexp do *not* have an alternation operator, so

```
grep 'a\|b'
```

Will typically not work in every `grep` (while a few like GNU `grep` support it as an extension).

```
grep -E 'a|b'
grep -e a -e b
grep 'a
b'
```

Will work in every `grep` though.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using grep

What if you used the after context switch to grep (`-A`) and specified a `1` to get the first line after a match?

```
$ grep -E -A 1 "name=|age=|class=|marks=" student.txt
```

#### Example

Sample file.

```
$ cat student.txt 
name=
1st line after name
2nd line after name
age=
1st line after age
2nd line after age
class=
1st line after class
2nd line after class
marks=
1st line after marks
2nd line after marks
```

Then when you execute the above command:

```
$ grep -E -A 1 "name=|age=|class=|marks=" student.txt
name=
1st line after name
--
age=
1st line after age
--
class=
1st line after class
--
marks=
1st line after marks
```

#### Using awk

As @RahulPatil suggested using the construct to `awk`:

```
'/string1/||/string2/||...'
```

Something like this would do what you're looking for.

```
$ awk '
  /name=/||/age=/||/class=/||/marks=/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+1]}; NR in nr
' student.txt
```

#### Example

```
$ awk '
  /name=/||/age=/||/class=/||/marks=/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+1]}; NR in nr
' student.txt
name=
1st line after name
age=
1st line after age
class=
1st line after class
marks=
1st line after marks
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the "-A" flag with grep? It will print lines of trailing context after the match. For example: `grep -A1 foo file.txt` will match and print lines with the word **foo** and also print the line immediately following.