# Print a line in stdout that matches an expression if the output contains another expression

Tags: sed, awk, grep

This might be a common/easy task but I couldn't figure out from examples on the web or manuals of awk/sed/grep.

So, here is the scenario:

- There is an internal command line tool that prints out a multi-line result for each line in an input file.
- I have an input file with 500K lines.
- In the output of the tool, there is always a line which is like "src: /some/directory"
- I want to extract this line if and only if there is the specific string "foo" in the same output.

The number of rows between these lines might be different, so this question is somewhat related but not exactly what I'm trying to do.
[Match multiple regular expressions from a single file using awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88721/match-multiple-regular-expressions-from-a-single-file-using-awk)

How can I do this using awk, sed or grep? I can do it using Python but I don't want to because I want to learn awk/sed and this might be a good example.

Here is what I tried with grep:

```
tool -inputfile | if grep "foo"; then grep "src: " ; fi > result.txt
```

This doesn't produce the result I expected, probably because of something related to buffering.

Trying with awk:

```
tool -inputfile | awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {if(match($i, "foo")) print ??? }}' > result.txt
```

How do I print the line that contains "src: " in this script?

Example outputs of the tool:

Output 1:

```
src: /usr/bin 
param1: value1 value2 
param2: "foo" 
param3: "bar" "spam" 
param4: "eggs" "spam" "spam"
```

Output 2:

```
src: /dev/null
param1: value1 value2
param2: "ham" "spam" "eggs"
```

So for these 2 cases, I am trying to extract just the 1st one, ie: src: /usr/bin

Comment: How are the records separated in the output of the internal tool? Can you provide a small example, please?

Comment: line by line, each line is like "parameter: value, value, value, ..." the values can be one or more

Comment: but is there anything **delimiting** each multiple-line record (such as a blank line between them)?

Comment: yes, a blank line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that `src:` occurs at the beginning of a line and that `foo` is enclosed in quotes and preceded by a space and that there must be a colon earlier in the line, use

```
awk 'BEGIN{a=0} /^$/{if(a==1) print b; a=0} /:.* "foo"/{a=1} /^src:/{b=$0} END{if(a==1) print b}'
```

We use the variable `a` to remember whether or not the pattern `foo` occurs in the input block, and the variable `b` to store the `src:` line. At the beginning, `a` is set to 0. Whenever we find an empty line (i.e., `^$`), we check the value of `a`, conditionally print `b`, and reset `a`. If we encounter `"foo"` preceded by a colon earlier in the line, we set `a` to 1. If we encounter `src:` at the beginning of a line (`^`), we store it in `b`. At the end, we check once more whether `a == 1`, if so, we print `b`.

Comment: Thanks, tried them on a small sample (of which I know the results). Awk script prints **only the last matching** case. And sed doesn't seem to be filtering properly, it prints all the cases.

Comment: Do you have several lines that contain `src:`? From your question, I had the impression that there is only one.

Comment: For each line in the input, the tool produces a new output. In each output there is only one line that contain "src: ". For the outputs of the sample file, I'm 100% sure that "src: " occurs only once. For the real file with 500K lines, it's highly unlikely but I will check nevertheless.

Comment: And the outputs are separated by what? Blank lines? Or does every `src:` start a new block?

Comment: ok, answer updated.

Comment: a blank line and yes every block (except the 1st) starts with src:

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Could you please explain the logic and the parameters because I want to learn awk.

Comment: @Uwe Half of this code is redundant. Why have the begin block ? All variables start at 0. Also what is this `/^$/{if(a==1) print b; a=0}` supposed to do ? The `/:.* "foo"/` doesn't need `.*` as it is checking it contains `"foo"` anyway.

Comment: @Jidder `/^$/{if(a==1) print b; a=0}` starts a new block. The input file for the awk script consists of several blocks separated by blank lines, and the `src:` line should be printed whenever *the corresponding* block contains `foo`. The `/:.* "foo"/` pattern checks for `"foo"` somewhere after the colon in the line. The begin block is just for clarity, but yes, it's redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Easy awk

```
awk '/src/{a=$0}/foo/{b=1}b&&a{print a;exit}'
```

If `src` or `foo` can be somewhere else in a different format or whatever

```
awk '/^src/{a=$0}/"foo"/{b=1}b&&a{print a;exit}'
```

If foo always comes after `src`

```
awk '/^src/{a=$0}/"foo"/{print a;exit}'
```

If there are multiple src blocks in a file and you want to print each one that contains foo

```
awk '/^src/{a=$0;b=0}/"foo"/{b=1}b&&a{print a;a=0}'
```

Comment: Correct me I'm wrong: If src is found, set a to first row. If foo is found set b to 1. If both a and b is true, print a and then exit?

Comment: @GaniSimsek yep, well it sets `a` to the line that `src` is on, is that what you wanted ?

Comment: Yes but for multiple blocks, so your last script accomplishes the task the way I wanted. The reason I asked is to learn more about awk. Your logic and your code is concise and coherent. Thank you.