# How to add a line after nth occurrence of a keyword using sed?

Tags: sed

Using sed, I want to add check after nth occurrence

Input:

```
DCR
DCR
DCR
```

Output:

```
DCR
DCR
check
DCR
```

Is it possible using sed?

Comment: `sed` is Turing complete, so it is possible. But something else, like `awk` or `perl` might be more suited to this task.

Comment: There is a duplicate here:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88038/print-matching-line-and-nth-line-from-the-matched-line/88051#88051

Comment: @val0x00ff it's very similar but I don't think it's a duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -z 's/DCR/&\ncheck/2' <input >output
```

For non-uptodate versions:

```
sed '/DCR/{p;s/.*/1/;H;g;/^\(\n1\)\{2\}$/s//check/p;d}' <input >output
```

If there are more than 1 occurence `DCR` in line:

```
sed '
/DCR/{p
      x                               # tests if already have met pattern
      /^\(\n\a\)\{2\}/!{              #+apropriate times and, if so, cancel
        x                             #+the rest of commands
        s/DCR/\a/g                    # exchange DCR by \a symbol
        s/^[^\a]*\|[^\a]*$//g         # delete everything before & after it  
        s/[^\a]\+/\n/g                # substitute everything between by \n
        H
        g
        /^\(\n\a\)\{2\}/s/.*/check/p} # add 'check' for double pattern
      d}' <input >output
```

Comment: The first one is OK (+1 for using `-z`); the second one works OK only if there's one pattern per line (try it with a file where the first two occurrences of _pattern_ are on the same line and the third is on another line). It is unclear though, whether the op wants to count lines matching pattern or just patterns...

Comment: @don_crissti It is rather different what OP asked but if you wants `'/DCR/{p;s/DCR/\a/g;H;g;s/\n\?[^\n\a]*/\n/g;/^\(\n\a\)\{2\}\n\?$/s/.*/check/p;d}'` where `\a` is `\x07` symbol (can be any which sure will not met in the text.

Comment: @Costas  I am getting below error for second command:
`sed:command garbled: /DCR/{p;s/.*/1/;H;g;/^\(\n1\)\{2\}$/s//check/p;d}`

Comment: @Menon Try to add `;` after last `d`. What version of `sed` do you use? (`sed --version`)

Comment: @Costas Now there is no error but there is no change in output. The version extension doesnot work in the unix environment I use. But it is pretty old version.

Comment: @Menon Try to divide script by `\n`ew lines instead of `;`. Other solution use `script-file` if your version support `-f` option. Any way try `man sed`.

Comment: `sed command garbled` is at least a Solaris error message. GNU `sed` doesn't writw any errors like that.

Answer (score 5):

With GNU sed, you can replace the *n*th pattern in a *line*

```
$ echo "foofoofoofoo" | sed 's/foo/&\nbar/2'
foofoo
barfoofoo
```

But for the *n*th line that contains the pattern, awk is easier:

```
awk -v n=2 -v patt=foo '{print} $0 ~ patt && ++count == n {print "bar"}' <<END
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
END
```

```
foo1
foo2
bar
foo3
foo4
```

Comment: There is a duplicate here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88038/print-matching-line-and-nth-line-from-the-matched-line/88051#88051

Comment: @glenn I want to add line after the line where nth occurrence of pattern occurs.

Comment: Be specific: after the nth line that contains the pattern? What happens if the pattern matches n times on the 1st line?

Comment: @glenn yes, after the nth line that contains the pattern.

Comment: This awk command meets that requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `sed` on a stack...

```sh
sed '/match$/N
     s/\n/&INSERT&/3;t
     $n;N;P;D'
```

That would insert *`INSERT`* following every 3rd *non-sequential* occurrence of *`match`* in input. It is the most efficient way I know to do it with `sed` because it does not attempt to store all lines that occur between different *`matches`*, nor does it necessitate buffer swaps or back-ref comparisons, but instead simply increments `sed`'s only means of counting at all - its line-number via its line-cycle.

There is some added overhead, of course - with each match pattern space gets a little bigger - but it is still the same stream, and there is no back-tracking. It's just *first-in,first-out* - which, as I think, is a method very well suited to `sed`. In fact, rather than going back to check for a match, `sed` can *advance further ahead* for each match. I'm a little proud of it, and don't know why I never thought of it before.

The version above, though, would squeeze repeats to some extent because it only works one line behind input. And the solution to that is to advance still further and requires only a little additional complexity in the form of a `b`ranch `:l`abel short-circuit loop inside the `N;P;D` loop to keep it current.

It works like this:

```sh
seq 100000| sed -ne':n
            s/\n/&\tCheck&\t/5p;t
            N;/0000$/bn'  -eD
```

...which, for me, prints...

```sh
49995
49996
49997
49998
49999
    Check
    50000
99995
99996
99997
99998
99999
    Check
    100000
```

You see, in order to maintain the count, it increments its line-buffer for each occurrence of *`match`* and tacks another line onto its sliding window on pattern space. In that way all that is needed to verify that the match has been found is to attempt to substitute away the `s///`*`nth`* `\n`ewline character in pattern space. If it can be done, we've encountered *`n matches`* so far, and `t`est can branch us out of the current iteration and clear the increment entirely.

In the example above the buffer is incremented once for every pattern-space which ends with the string *`0000`*. When 5 of those are found, `sed` prints the current pattern-space - and its whole buffer - and clears the counter.

For your thing:

```sh
printf DCR\\n| tee - - - - - |
sed -e:n -e's/\n/&\tCheck&\t/2;t
     $n;    N;/DCR$/bn' -eP\;D

DCR
DCR
    Check
    DCR
DCR
DCR
    Check
    DCR
```

Now, if you wanted to mark *only* the *`nth`* occurrence, it's also easy:

```sh
printf DCR\\n        |
tee - - - - - - - - -|
sed -e:n -e's/\n/&\tCheck&\t/3;te
     $n;  N;/DCR$/bn' -e'P;D;:e
     n;be'
```

...if you really look at it, it might occur to you that we only barely scratched the surface here...

```
DCR
DCR
DCR
    Check
    DCR
DCR
DCR
DCR
DCR
DCR
DCR
```

Comment: Does this work with POSIX sed? The spec said `t` with no label will branch to the end of script. i tried with three sed from heirloom toolchest, they worked.

Comment: @cuonglm - yes, it works. I tested it with those as well. But you've maybe misunderstood the statement *`b`ranching to the end of the script*. That is what it does, of course. The *end of script* is not the *end of file* - for each line-cycle `sed` reads its script all the way - well, normally. It can be done otherwise - like I did in that `!!` answer where the script is read from start to finish in tandem with the infile. Anyway, when you *`b`ranch to end of script* you `b`ranch out to the next line-cycle to try the script again.

Comment: Well, I really misunderstood the spec, but not like you thought. I think end of script mean the end of the `-e` part associated with `t` command. My bad!

Comment: @cuonglm - oh yeah. that makes sense. but `sed` concatenates all of its scripts into a single one before ever getting started - so by the time it starts executing there only ever is the one.

Comment: @cuonglm - you didn't like this answer or something? i only found out i could do this yesterday. This is a *cool* answer.

Comment: No, I *really* like this answer, I just try myself to figure out all of the part in answer. Thinking `sed` way is cool and sometime, it's hard to me. I always learn some things new in your `sed` answers.

Comment: @cuonglm - well, i always do too - that's i do them. Its why i do any of it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a direct answer in sed. In awk, on the other hand, it is easy:

```
echo -e "DCR\nDCR\nDCR" |\
awk 'BEGIN {t=0}; { print }; /DCR/ { t++; if ( t==2) { print "check" } }'
```

Comment: I used this command in bash script: `awk 'BEGIN {t=0}; { print }; /DCR/ { t++; if ( t==2) { print "check" } }' file > newfile` But I am getting error:`awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
`

Answer (score 2):

### GNU sed

`sed` is not well suited for this task, but of course you can still do it. Here is one way that saves a string that is `n` long in the hold-space, and uses that to count the number of `DCR` occurrences:

```
n=2

((yes | head -n$n | tr -d \\n; echo); cat infile) | 
sed '
  1 {h;d}            # save counting string
  /DCR/ {            #
    x; s/.//; x      # n--
    T chk            # if n=0 goto "chk"
  }
  P;D 
  :chk               # insert check
  i\check
  :a; N; ba          # print rest of file
'
```

### awk

As noted by *glenn*, awk is much cleaner, here is a golfed version, but similar logic:

```
<infile awk '!n { print "check" } /DCR/ { n-- } 1' n=2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    sed '2 a\
    check
    ' file
```

Append after line 2 with a newline then add the word "check" with another newline and print the whole file to standard out.

Answer (score -1):

AWK solution is a lot easy to read for this kind of tasks, here is just a correction to steviethecat's solution (the ; won't work for awk, need to replace it with a newline):

```
echo -e "DCR\nDCR\nDCR" | awk 'BEGIN {t=0}

{ print }

/DCR/ { t++; if ( t==2) { print "check" } }'
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L.SE. Please explain why the correction is needed, and you may get an upvote.

Comment: The one steviethecat posted has problem, and an user has used it and got error.

Comment: Update your Answer by Clicking Edit... Don't tell us in a comment, i.e explain what the error the user got, and then tell us how that code fixes it.  You've done half of that, but posting an untested code blob is  discouraged.