# Verification of 4th line value after pattern occurrence

Tags: shell-script

I have a text file I need to verify, and I am trying to figure out how to check that an expected value exists.

An example of my file is

```
InitialPattern:
   Value1=somevalue
   Value2=somevalue
   Value3=somevalue
   InstallationName=InstallationX
```

I don't care about lines 2-4, but I need to verify that in line 5

```
   InstallationName=Installation1
```

To throw a wrench in it, this line does not always exist, at which point the pattern starts again with

```
InitialPattern:
```

What I have so far kind of works, but not in the case that the line does not occur altogether:

```
      instName="Installation1"
      installationNames=$(cat file.txt | grep InstallationName)
      IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a array <<< "$installationNames"
      for element in "${array[@]}"
      do
         if [[ "$element" =~ "$instName" ]]; then
           test="pass"
         else
           test="fail"
           break
         fi
      done
```

any ideas? I was looking at this post: [Print Matching line and nth line from the matched line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88038/print-matching-line-and-nth-line-from-the-matched-line)
Where the user got the forth line after an pattern occurrence - I was thinking if I could store this value I could compare it to the expected value, but I am not entirely sure how to store it yet.

Any guidance is welcome!

Comment: @ThomasDickey, it may be worth waiting until you get [2000 reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) (since you're not far off) before making all those (useful) edits as [some people are getting annoyed at having to approve each and everyone of them](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/3704). Glad to see you here BTW.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e'/\n/D;t'       -e:N  \
    -e'/^InitialPattern/ N' \
    -e'/\nInitialPattern/D' \
    -e's/\n/&/4;tD'         \
    -e'$!s//&/; tN'   -e:D  \
    -e's/ *\(\(Installation\)Name=\2[X0-9]\{1,\}\) *$/\1/;D'
```

I'm not really sure what you want to do with it, but that only prints the last line in a sequence which matches your specifications.

Here. I wrote one that counts. So you can just change the `4` to whatever you want if you need to - the number you enter there is how many newlines must lie between the most recently occurring *`InitialPattern`* match and the *`Installation`* line match in order to get it to print it.

Comment: possibly miss 4th `n`

Comment: @Costas - what 4th? The 4th line is 3 `n`ext lines away from this one. oh. but asker wants the *5th* line. thanks, man.

Answer (score 1):

```
test=$(
    sed '
        /InitialPattern:/! d
        n
        n
        n
        $!n
        /.*Installation[0-9]\+$/d
        s/.*/FAIL/p
        q
        ' file.txt)
test=${test:-PASS}
```