# match specific line and print all lines except the following line

Tags: shell-script, python

I have similar instructions like in the thread [Print Matching line and nth line from the matched line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88038/print-matching-line-and-nth-line-from-the-matched-line)

I would need to match the specific line, print it, then remove the following line (1st following line) and then print the rest until to match the specific line etc.

In other words, I need to remove only lines with `</s>` which follows the line starting with `<doc`.

My file:

```
<doc>
</s>
<s>
Bla
bla
bla
.
</s>
<s>
Bla
bla
bla
.
</s>
</doc>
<doc>
</s>
...
```

My required output:

```
<doc>
<s>
Bla
bla
bla
.
</s>
<s>
Bla
bla
bla
.
</s>
</doc>
<doc>
...
```

Comment: It's not a code-writing service. You have to show us that you tried do to something

Comment: Of course the comment of @mrc02_kr is right. But  +1 for giving a precise definition of the question, even with input and output. That's unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not too hard to figure out with basic `sed` knowledge:

```
sed '/<doc>/{n;/<\/s>/d;}'
```

For lines with `<doc>`, print it and read the next line with `n` and then, if this folloing line contains `</s>` (slash needs to be escaped), delete it with `d`.

More verbose explanation: `/expression/{command;command;...;}` means to execute the commands only on lines that match the pattern, so all other lines simply get printed as they are, while for the `<doc>` line, `n` is executed. This command prints the current line and reads the next one, so the following commands are executed on the next line. Here comes another command (`d`) with an "address" (`/<\/s>/`), thus the line is `d`eleted only if it contains `</s>`, otherwise is printed. In either case the script will continue with the following line.

Comment: thanks, this works perfectly! I did not know about using "{n".

Comment: Actually, `{n` is not a command. I added are more detailed explanation for you. If the script solves your question, please consider marking it as answered for future readers.

Comment: thanks, for the detailed explanation, now I completely understand.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -z -i 's:<doc>\n</s>:<doc>:g' infile.txt
```

This is replacing `<doc>` followed by `</s>` with only `<doc>`. The `sed`'s `-i` flag is used for in place replace; and the `g` flag is to replace *all* occurences. `-z` cause to separate lines with NULL characters.

Comment: `\n` in the pattern is a POSIX requirement supported by all `sed` implementations I ever met. But as `sed` works linewise this can't ever match unless you join lines first or use `-z` option with GNU `sed`

Comment: 1) making `-z` default would break 99% of all scripts! 2) Without `-z` your script doesn't work with GNU `sed` 4.4 (like it doesn't with any other version). 3) I suppose you are talking about `\n` in the replacement string. In the matching pattern I can't think of any version not supporting it.

Comment: The second version will still not work on any `sed` version.

Comment: @Philippos Correct, I removed that part from my answer, but may I ask you why `sed` doesn't recognize newline there in find part and again I should use `-z` with that?. thank you

Comment: Because the default behaviour of `sed` is to read one line of input to the buffer ("pattern space"), apply the script on it and proceed with the next line. So there will never be a newline in the pattern space unless you use a command like `N`, which appends the next line to the pattern space, letting you have two lines with a newline in between. You can run `N;P;D` patterns to always have two consecutive lines in the buffer, but that's beyond what can be explained in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

As you marked `shell_script` I would suggest ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '/^<doc>/ && getline nl > 0 && nl!~/^<\/s>/{ print $0 RS nl }1' file
```

---

The output:

```
<doc>
<s>
Bla
bla
bla
.
</s>
<s>
Bla
bla
bla
.
</s>
</doc>
<doc>
...
```

Comment: This is not the real output of your script. Your script also removes the last line like all other lines following `<doc>`, although the question says *I need to remove only lines with </s> which follows the line starting with <doc>*

Comment: @Philippos, see my update

Comment: I suppose this works (I can't verify this as some shell magic gives me `!~/^: event not found` error for your script), and it confirms me to prefer `sed` over `awk` for most tasks. (-;

Comment: @Philippos, strange, what's your shell that giving error?

Comment: `bash` 4.3.30 as well as 4.4.12, almost no custom settings. But I've seen it messing with `!` even inside single quotes before. It's rare, but nasty. Not related to your script though.

Comment: Oh! I just realize this only happens if I `echo` the text and pipe it to your `awk` script. No problems when working on a file. But your sciprt gives me a trailing `<doc>` line for some reason (-:

Comment: @Philippos, you may look https://ibb.co/bsoLYa

Comment: Yes, see my last comment. It happens only with piped input.

Comment: I did analyze the problem. I suspect it's a bug, see [my question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390931/bash-history-expansion-inside-single-quotes-after-a-double-quote-inside-the-sam)

Comment: @Philippos, yes, you have posted an interesting question. I wish it was successfully answered