# Bash: History expansion inside single quotes after a double quote inside the same line

Tags: bash, quoting, history-expansion

I took a closer look on this phenomenon after I stumbled over it in two other questions today. I've tried all of this with the default `set -H` (history expansion on).

To test a script, I often do things like `echo`ing a multi-line string and pipe it through a script, but in some cases it gives an error:

```
$ echo "foo
bar" | sed '/foo/!d'
bash: !d': event not found
>
```

The `!` seems to trigger history expansion, although it is enclosed with single quotes. The problem seems to be the occurrence of the double quote in the same line, because

```
$echo $'foo\nbar' | sed '/foo/!d'
```

works as well as

```
$echo "foo
bar" |
> sed '/foo/!d'
```

My suspicion: History expansion is applied linewise, so the `'` after a single `"` is considered to be escaped, so the following `!` is not escaped.

Now my question: Is this a bug or expected behavior? Reproduced with `bash` versions 4.2.30 and 4.4.12.

Comment: Just tried with `zsh` (history expansion on): No such problem. Really seems to be a bug in `bash`

Comment: The problem is poor implementation of history expansion in `bash`. You can disable the whole implementation by adding `set +H` to `.bashrc`. In that case, `bash` never attempts to do any history expansion stuff anywhere (that is, behave like proper bourne shell) and you'll have less nasty surprises.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reported this to `bug-bash@gnu.org` and got this [answer](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-09/msg00017.html):

> History expansion is explicitly line-oriented, and always has been. There's
> not a clean way to make it aware of the shell's current quoting state
> (mostly since it's a library independent of the shell). Maybe there's a way
> to use one of the existing callback functions to do it.

This sounds to me like "*this is not a bug, because we can't do it any better with the current implementation*".

**Update**

I lost interest in this subject after switching to `zsh`. Now I tried with `bash` version 5.1.4 and found the problem can't be reproduced anymore. So somewhere between 4.4.12 and 5.1.4, somebody did fix this.

Comment: "we can't do it any better with the current implementation" sounds like an implementation bug for me.

Comment: I can reproduce the bug in v4.4.18, but not in v5.0.0, so it's probably v5 that fixed it.