# Run command from history with parameters

Tags: bash, command-history, csh

Whenever I need to type a long command I find that the exclamation mark to refer to history very handy. For example, `!ssh` can be used to invoke the last `ssh` command I used. However I cannot get it to work when space-delimited arguments are added to the search.

By executing `!ssh -i`, I expect to the last command starting with the string "ssh -i" to be executed. However, the actual command that is invoked is the last `ssh` command with whatever argument, and then "-i" was appended to the command.

I can use `!?ssh -i?` but that is meant to do something different and I believe there should be a simple way to achieve this. I am also reluctant to type `history|grep ...` every time.

So how can I refer to a command in history that starts with a string containing space, as stated above?

**Edit** It seems that I have not explained the question clear enough. Let's say I have the following history

```
ssh -i identity host1
echo ssh -i
ssh host2
```

now if I run `!ssh`, the third command, namely `ssh host2` will be executed. I expect to type `!ssh -i` to get the first command executed, but `ssh host2 -i` is executed instead (which results in an error). I can use `!?ssh -i?` to execute the first command **only if the second command doesn't exist**.

Comment: Why not use ctrl-R`ssh -i` instead? I never use history expansion, but always history search, because (a) it always works the same way and (b) it keeps me from mistakes because I can see the line to execute before I really do it and (c) I can do `set +H` by default, so the bad implementation of `bash` history expansion won't [mess up my scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390931/bash-history-expansion-inside-single-quotes-after-a-double-quote-inside-the-sam).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It makes sense to me. I am just not yet used to Ctrl-R. I will consider switching to it. For the "never use history expansion" part, history expansion is useful if you want to embed it into a larger command.

Comment: @Philippos Just noticed that Ctrl-R takes me to the second command, not the first.

Comment: Come on! You just invented the `echo ssh -i` line to exclude using Ctrl-R!

Comment: Sorry about it. I just realized that when you posted that comment, my edit has not even started.

Comment: Does `ssh -i` followed immediately (no newline) by the PageUp key do what you want?

Comment: It doesn't work in the current state. Maybe I need to put something in `.inputrc`?

Comment: Yes it works now after I put two lines in `.inputrc`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by Mark Plotnick. I have found a solution. Although it is not using bash history expansion. (I believe using bash history expansion to achieve this is impossible after reading [section 9.3.1 of bash reference manual].(https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html)

The solution is to put the following lines in `~/.inputrc`, or uncomment the corresponding lines in `/etc/inputrc` for global effect.

```
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

The corresponding code can be found by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and then the <kbd>PageUp</kbd> key, and the commands are taken from [section 8.4.2 of bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html).

After that I can use <kbd>PageUp</kbd> key to go to the first command as Mark commented.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to change the default behavior of bash's HISTCONTROL. 
From this post:
[Why is bash not storing commands that start with spaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115917/why-is-bash-not-storing-commands-that-start-with-spaces)

> > HISTCONTROL
> >
> > A colon-separated list of values controlling how commands are saved on the history list. If the list of values includes ignorespace, lines which begin with a space character are not saved in the history list. A value of ignoredups causes lines matching the previous history entry to not be saved. A value of ignoreboth is shorthand for ignorespace and ignoredups.

If you want to skip the ! and allow for spaces then I suggest you try a shell other than bash.  Fish shell works perfectly for what you're asking :)

> sudo apt-get install fish

to try it from your bash shell just type, 'fish'

If you like it you can persist it with:

> chsh -s /usr/bin/fish

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am referring to spaces in the middle of the command, not the spaces at the beginning of the command.