# How does this sed command to extract an IPv6 address work?

Tags: linux, sed

I was given a command to extract an IPv6 address:

```
/usr/bin/ip a | grep inet6 | grep -vE 'fe80|host' | sed -e 's/^.*inet6 \([^ ]*\)\/.*$/\1/;t;d'
```

Could someone please break down the `sed` substitution for me?

The sed command also works without the `;t;d`

Comment: Quick non-answer: start with the leading pipeline so you can see what the `sed` is acting on. What do you know (if anything) about Regular Expressions?

Comment: Are you sure it's `/usr/bin/ip` and not one of `/usr/sbin/ip` or even `/sbin/ip`?

Comment: `awk` would be better for this.  e.g. `ip addr | awk '/inet6/ && ! /fe80|host/ { print $2 }'`.  In English, that's roughly: on lines that contain "inet6" but don't contain "host" or "fe80", print field two.

Comment: roaima, on my MX-Linux VM system it is indeed /usr/bin/ip

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by simplifying your expression a little...

```
LINE=" inet6 fd86:73ea:ff6b:0:141b:ca40:741b:ec0c/64 scope global noprefixroute"
echo $LINE | sed -e' s/^.*inet6 \([^ ]*\)\/.*$/\1/;t;d'
```

the **-e** means that the next argument is the sed script.

's/pattern/replace/' means find "pattern" in the input and substitute with "replace".

Here pattern is `/^.*inet6 \([^ ]*\)\/.*$/`

The '/' marks the beginning & end of the pattern of the pattern.

The ^ and $ characters always match the start and end of the input string respectively. Obvs the input string will always have a start and an end - these become useful when you want to match or replace elements relative to these positions.

`.*` means zero or more occurrences of any character. In $LINE above, this matches a single space character.

`inet6`  means the literal string "inet6 " (with a trailing space).

The `\(pattern\)` brackets tell sed to not only match the sub-pattern in the input, but to store it for use later.

The `\/` means match a literal '/' (see above - without the prefix, the '/' character denotes a structural element in the pattern).

`.*$` simply means match the any remaining characters up to the end of the line.

`/` marks the end of the pattern.

`\1` This is the replacement. Here 1 refers to the first stored match found by the pattern (but there is only one).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to learn something, which I appreciate. symcbean explained the `sed` command to you, but I'd like to add some more things you can learn from the code. You can learn to avoid bad habits. (-;

1. The whole command is piped through two `grep`s and an `sed`, which is almost always nonsense. In `sed`, you can *address* lines by preceeding them with a regular expression, which can do the `grep` functionality on the fly like `sed -n '/foo/s/pattern/replace/p'` to do the replacement only on lines with `foo`. So '/inet6/!d' could delete all lines without (`!`) `inet6` and then you could replace the second `grep` by `/fe80/d;/host/d` (or, with extended regular expression option `-E`: `/fe08|host/d`).
2. The `-e` is optional if there is only one command (or several commands concatenated by `;`). Things get easier to read if you leave away superfluous stuff.
3. As already pointed out, beginning a regular expression by `^.*` is nonsense. The greedy `*` will match anything from the beginning anyhow, so don't distract the reader with an unnecessary anchor.
4. Same applies to `.*$` at the end. Remove the anchor.
5. If the pattern contains a slash, use a different separator for the `s` command. Almost any character is allowed so why should one make the expression harder to read by filling it with backslashes? Underscores are good alternatives, for example: `s_.*inet6 \([^ ]*\)/.*_\1_`
6. Working with `\(…\)` and `\1` can be useful, but if this is just about extracting the middle part, it can be more comprehensive to simply remove beginning and ending separately: `s/.*inet6 //;s_/.*__`
7. According to the `sed` definition, the `t` command is optionally followed by a jump mark, which would be `;d` in this case. Uncommon, but legal. The GNU version of `sed` doesn't allow a semicolon in jump marks, but interprets this as a command-separating semicolon. In this case there would be no jump mark, which means "if a substitution was made, jump to the end of the script". But other `sed` versions will throw an error. It's really nasty to make a script incompatible for such a detail! This could be avoided by separate scripts, for example `-e '…;t' -e d`. Or by writing commands in new lines.
8. In this case the idea of the `t;d` was to avoid messed output if the substitution failed. A good idea, but there is a real tool for that, the `p` flag to the `s` command: `s_.*inet6 \([^ ]*\)/.*_\1_p;d`. If a replacement was made, `p`rint the buffer. Easier to read and portable.
9. The trailing `d` command could be replaced by the `-n` option to suppress default output, but that's a matter of taste.

Finally we can compare the commands

```
/usr/bin/ip a | grep inet6 | grep -vE 'fe80|host' | sed -e 's/^.*inet6 \([^ ]*\)\/.*$/\1/;t;d'

/usr/bin/ip a | sed '/inet6/!d; /fe80/d; /host/d; s/.*inet6 //; s_/.*__p; d'
```

or with ERE and `-n` instead of `d`:

```
/usr/bin/ip a | sed -En '/inet6/!d; /fe80|host/d ;s/.*inet6 //; s_/.*__p'
```

Code golfers would probably write

```
sed -En '/fe80|host/!s_.*inet6 ([^ ]*)/.*$_\1_p'
```

but this seems less readable to me.

Comment: Thank you Philippos, great expalnation!

I have run into another issue, hoping you have a fix for:
`-bash-4.2$ ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" 192.168.210.21 "hostname;/usr/sbin/ip a | sed '/inet6/!d; /fe80/d; /host/d; s/.*inet6 //; s_/.*__p; d'"
-bash: !d: event not found`

Googling around, I found out it hast to do with history expansion, however, I couldn't find a fix that worked.

Regards,
Bjoern

Comment: Yes, there was a bug in `bash` for a long time, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390931/bash-history-expansion-inside-single-quotes-after-a-double-quote-inside-the-sam If you can't update to `bash` 5.x, do `set +H` to switch off history expansion. I recommend that anyhow, because very few people use it, but many get annoyed by it.

Comment: So here's something interesting; I first attempted to string the set command before the actual ip command:  `set +H && ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" 192.168.210.21 "hostname;/usr/sbin/ip a | sed '/inet6/!d; /fe80/d; /host/d; s/.*inet6 //; s_/.*__p; d'"`
This did not work, however if I execute the set command `set +H` first, then the actual ip command, it will work.  I was hoping to do this with a one-liner.  
Any ideas?

Regards,

Comment: Put the `set +H` in your `~/.bashrc` to get rid of that buggy feature forever. (-:

Comment: Thank you Philippos!